# Converting bytes inside a tuple to string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a tuple full of bytes and i need to convert these bytes into one single utf-8 string, how can i  do that?

```
data = tuple([0, 4, 4, 6, 1, 53])
print(data as utf-8 string?)
```

Comment: What's the result you expect to get? `'\x00\x04\x04\x06\x015'`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey Yes, that's what i need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = bytes(tuple([0, 4, 4, 6, 1, 53])).decode('utf-8')
```

output:

```
'\x00\x04\x04\x06\x015'
```

functions used:

```
bytes() - convert an iterable to a bytes like object
decode('utf-8') - decode bytes to utf8
```